# Rep from closed sites appears in the Area 51 total but not the combined flair

Tags: bug, area-51, combined-flair

My usercard on Area 51 (the kind that contains my total SE rep and the sites I'm active on) shows a combined reputation (18,234) that is noticeably more than the sum of the reputation I have on each site shown (16,852). The difference is exactly equal to the rep I had on the now closed [Deep Web](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/87978/deep-web) site. It's been several weeks since the site's closure, so caching probably isn't the issue. I have more than 200 rep on Area 51, so it's counted in the image flair.

The correct, lower combined rep figure appears in chat and on my flair image. The only place I've found with the higher figure is the Area 51 usercard. Is that intended?